# How do I determine if this line is parallel, perpendicular, or neither to these planes?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the line $x=-3$ , $y= -5t$ , $z= 5-3t$ and try to see if it is parallel or perpendicular to these planes:

$15x+12y−20z=5$

$2x−5y−2z=−13$

$8x+12y−20z=−100 $

$−15y−9z=24$

I know that the dot product of (0,-5,-3) and (15,12,-20) is 0 so the first one is parallel, and the cross product for (0, -5, -3) and (0, -15, -9) yields (0, 0, 0) so the fourth one is perpendicular. How would I go about the second and third plane? I thought they would both not be either, since the dot and cross product did not result in zeros, but that was incorrect. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: You computed the dot product wrong for the third one.

Comment: The 3rd one is also parallel -- check your dot product again, and (2,-5,-2) is neither.

Answer (score 0):

Boi, redo your calculations.

And have a look at:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product

and at:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product

Comment: Ah, I realized I had written down (-3, 0, 5) dot (8, 12, -20) instead of (0, -5, -3). In the question the line is written in component form which lead to my confusion. Thanks!